# Gridview index out of range when rows are returning

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to change the CSS styling of the first row in a gridview:

```
protected void hoursReportGridView_OnRowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        GridViewRow firstRow = hoursReportGridView.Rows[0];
        firstRow.CssClass = "firstRow";
    }
}
```

I am getting this error: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

In every instance there are multiple rows returned so I don't understand the issue[image]
'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the first row exists in `GridView.Rows` **after** `RowDataBound`. So you can access it afterwards. So i would use `DataBound` instead. Note that you also set the first row on every row since `RowDataBound` is triggered for every row in the grid.

```
protected void hoursReportGridView_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(this.hoursReportGridView.Rows.Count > 0)
        hoursReportGridView.Rows[0].CssClass = "firstRow";
}
```

Another option is to use [`GridViewRow.RowIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.rowindex.aspx)

```
protected void hoursReportGridView_OnRowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if(e.Row.RowIndex == 0)
            e.Row.CssClass = "firstRow";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
protected void hoursReportGridView_OnRowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowIndex == 0)
        {
            e.Row.CssClass = "firstRow";

    }
}
```

Comment: Not downvoting, but this is a bad answer, because you are running this check for every row in the GridView.  RowDataBound event is designed for executing code on every row.  This is a very inefficient way of doing something for just one row.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to do that on the databind for **every row**?

Just do it in `Page_Load`:

```
// Run this after any binding calls, obviously
if(hoursReportGridView.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    hoursReportGridView.Rows[0].CssClass = "firstRow";
}
```